# How to avoid auto committing of insert statements

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am writing a php interface for an Oracle SQL database (php 5.3.3 and oci 12.1.0.2.0). The data base is quite big, has multiple constraints, triggers, and links on and among the tables. During testing I noticed that, even though I commented out the oci_commit() function and I am calling the oci_rollback method in case my code notices a failure (i.e. oci_error is not empty), some of my insert statements are committed. I am running a self-made class for the data base connection; the writeSql function is looking like this:

```
public function writeSql($sql, &$handlers=array(), $attrib=OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT) {
    $this->parse = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
    foreach($handlers as $handler){
        $key = $this->upper ? strtoupper($handler->short) : strtolower($handler->short);
        if($handler->dtype==OCI_B_BLOB)
            oci_bind_by_name($this->parse, $key, $handler->link, -1, $handler->dtype);
        else
            oci_bind_by_name($this->parse, $key, $handler->link, $handler->dtype);
    }
    $this->exec = oci_execute($this->parse, $attrib);
    return $this->exec;
}
```

Ignore the handlers part. The relevant thing is, that I'm always using `$attrib=OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT` (I just did a grep of my dir and there is no function nowhere that redefines this parameter, so its always the default). And as said, I commented out explicitly the `oci_commit` call.

How is it possible then that some inserts are still committed? I noticed it by receiving errors that some uniqueness constraints are violated. Using the developer I can see the entries in the DB though they should not have been committed.

Thank you and regards,
c.

***EDIT:*** now that I've posted this I had a thought: whenever I open the DB connection (basically for every request by the user), I run an 'alter session' command (due to the date format blabla). I guess this does an implicit commit. But wouldn't all insert statements of the past session when closing the connection be discarded, i.e. effectively rolled back?

***EDIT2:*** I just added a rollback statement before closing the connection. But apparently this does not cure it. So it's not what I thought it was in the first EDIT remarks, but instead, the insert statements seem to be committed right away. At least some of them.

***EDIT3:*** Ok this is kinda strange. What I did now was to add a rollback and a print statement (and a truncation of the rest of the code) after every insert statement until I arrived at the point at which the commit is done. It is done at a nested select statement (!), which looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT SL.STATUSID, TO_CHAR(SL.CREATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') CREATETIME, TO_CHAR(SL.EVENTDATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6') EVENTDATE FROM  STATUSLOCATION SL LEFT OUTER JOIN STATUSES S ON SL.STATUSID=S.ID_STATUSES WHERE SL.EQENTRYID=xxxxxx AND SL.EVENTDATE = (SELECT MAX(SL.EVENTDATE) FROM EQUIPMENT E LEFT OUTER JOIN STATUSLOCATION SL ON E.ID_EQUIPMENT=SL.EQENTRYID WHERE E.ID_EQUIPMENT=xxxxxx AND SL.STATUSID IS NOT NULL)
```

The insert is to the `EQUIPMENT` table. If I truncate the code before this query, the inserted equipment is rolled back. If I put the truncation after this query, the inserted line is committed and I can see it in the developer (and when repeating it I get the error on the violation of the uniqueness constraint..). How can a select, even though it is nested and whatnot, do a commit after all..?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use PDO and transactions to handle this? I have a rather complex set of constraints that I've wrapped in a transaction (with a try/catch block) and if something doesn't go right a rollback leaves everything as it was.

Comment: Right.. There is not really any good reason other than historical evolution of the code and some external constraints. Unfortunately we are now in a state where it does not really make sense to rewrite the whole database connection setup.

Comment: To answer your last edit your probably can't. The commit on that nested select is probably the DB engine making sure things are in a consistent state before doing the rest of the statement. I can't imagine that you'll find a way around it other than making it a separate statement which is still likely to result in a commit.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I have one more clue: it might be because of some internal buffer that is created in that data base class that I'm using, where maybe some of the data is tried to be inserted twice. But I haven't checked this hypothesis yet (and it should have shown at other occasions too). If it turns out to be wrong, well, you just answered that case then already. So maybe I need to rethink the logic of my interface... Thank you!